# How to increment a numeric string '0000000001' in python?

Tags: python, string, increment

I have a function `getNextSeqNo()`. I want it to increment the numeric string when it is called, i.e. `0000000000` to `0000000001`, and then to `0000000002`. How do I do it?

I have written it as follows:

```
def __init__(self) :
    self.seq = '0000000000'

def getNextSeqNo(self) :
    self.seq = str(int(self.seq) +1)
    return(self.seq)
```

I am getting 1 as the output instead of `0000000001`.

Comment: I am new to python so had no idea about the format specifiers. Thanks a lot guys, works perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could convert the string to an int and use something like

```
self.seq = '%010d' % (int(self.seq) + 1)
return self.seq
```

If you didn't need `self.seq` to be a string you could do

```
def __init__(self) :
    self.seq = 0

def getNextSeqNo(self) :
    self.seq += 1
    return '%010d' % self.seq
```

Answer (score 6):

Quickest and easiest, although certainly not clearest:

```
str(int('9' + self.seq) + 1)[1:]
```

It works by adding a leading digit before converting to integer, to retain all the leading zeros, then stripping off that leading digit after converting back to string. It has the advantage of not requiring you to know in advance how many digits are required.

Comment: quite unclean, and raises several boundary issues.

Comment: @njzk2, not sure what you mean by "unclean", and there's only one boundary issue I can think of - but it's a big one.

Comment: if the number is negative, the minus sign will be striped. If the number is 9*x, the result will be 0*(x+1), resulting in a/ wrong value b/ wrong number of digits. (I would probably go with `'1' + self.seq' for that second reason.) That's 2 boundary issues (ok, may be not quite several). As for being unclean, I mean that the code does not carry the meaning of the operation performed.

Answer (score 4):

Format your number, with [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
self.seq = format(int(self.seq) + 1, '010d')
```

better still, don't store a string but an integer and return the formatted version:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.seq = 0

def getNextSeqNo(self):
    self.seq += 1
    return format(self.seq, '010d')
```

Format with `010d` outputs your integer as a 0-padded string with 10 characters:

```
>>> format(0, '010d')
'0000000000'
>>> format(42, '010d')
'0000000042'
```

Comment: +1 for storing an integer, not an integer-like string.

Answer (score 3):

There are many answers. Here is another one:

```
import string
seq = 1
string.zfill(seq, 10)
# '0000000001'
# works with strings too:
string.zfill('00001', 10)
# '0000000001'
```

or

```
seq = 1
str(seq).zfill(10)
# '0000000001'
```

Note how [`string.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) takes directly an int as parameter.

Comment: never new that method existed!

Answer (score 1):

You should store the current numeric value as an `int` instead, and generate strings from that on the fly.

```
>>> i = 0
>>> "{0:010d}".format(i)
'0000000000'

>>> i += 1
>>> "{0:010d}".format(i)
'0000000001'
```

It's a bad idea to store numeric values in a string form just because that's how you'd like to present them (or use in some context where a string is required).

Then `getNextSeqNo` becomes this:

```
def getNextSeqNo(self):
    ret = "{0:010d}".format(self._seq_i)
    self._seq_i += 1
    return ret
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using string formatting:

```
new_s = '{:0>{}}'.format(str(int(s)+1),len(s))

print new_s
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is, not to keep the sequence in a string, but format the sequence number when needed:

```
class SeqNo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.seq = 0

    def next(self):
        self.seq += 1
        return '%10d' % self.seq
```

Comment: "in an int" you meant.